# Sql query results to excel file using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, ssms

I am trying to export the results of a query to an excel file. I use ssms for my query and I am using PowerShell to get the file.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "Main" -Database "play" -Query "SELECT * FROM LOG1" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\file.csv" -v
```

I get I file is a csv format but when I change it to excel it's not supported because the lines dont match

Comment: `Out-File` won't create a CSV file, it'll create a plain-text file with _for-display_ representations. Did you mean to use [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)?

Comment: I'd rather store the results in a variable to see how the format is and based on that I will Convertto-csv and export to csv if it makes sense for CSV.